# Color correspondance in tikz and pyplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, plot

I draw a graph with pyplot, which I save in pdf format.
I then want to draw a line with the same color in tikz, however colors mismatch.

I get this result:
[image]

I create my graph with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys


x=numpy.arange(0,10,0.1)
y=x
plt.plot(x,y,color='green', linewidth=15)
plt.savefig('graph.pdf')
plt.show()
```

, and later include it in my document like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    


\centering
green: \tikz{\draw[green,ultra thick] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This is just my MWE, I would like to have a general approach working for all colors, as I have many more colors in my actual thesis document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that if you define the colours in the same way in both cases, they would match. Both `xcolor` and `matplotlib` allow you to use RGB tuples, with values in the range zero to one, to define colors, so you could probably say e.g.

```
green = (0,1,0)
plt.plot(x,y,color=green)
```

in `matplotlib`, and

```
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\draw [green] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

in your LaTeX document.

## An example

Just as an example, and to give `pythontex` a go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\begin{document}

\tikz\draw[line width=3mm,green] (0,0) -- (5,0);

\begin{pycode}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
green = (0,1,0)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
ax.plot([0,1],[0,1],color=green,linewidth=3)
fig.savefig('fig.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
\end{pycode}
\includegraphics{fig}
\end{document}
```

Compile with

```
pdflatex filename.tex
pythontex filename
pdflatex filename
```

and you get

[image]

Comment: Short, concise and correct ! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: What about other colors, e.g. yellow (combination of rgb), which I only find integer values in web color pickers, how do I convert those 8-bit values to 0-1 needed in pyplot/tex?

Comment: @cschmol Integers in the range [0,255]? Divide them by 255.